# Rails user rating, can only rate myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rating

I am trying to set up a 5 star rating system so users can rate other users. At the moment everything is working, (create, delete, update etc...) but only the logged in user can rate himself. I cannot rate other users. I get no errors, it just redirects to the user profile page as it should but without added a rating to that user.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :reviews
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

reviews_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :find_user
 before_action :find_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

 def new
   @review = Review.new
 end

 def create
   @review = Review.new(review_params)
   @review.user_id = current_user.id
   if @review.save
     redirect_to user_path(@user)
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
   if @review.update(review_params)
     redirect_to user_path(@user)
   else
     render 'edit'
   end
 end

 def destroy
   @review.destroy
   redirect_to user_path(@user)
 end

 private

 def review_params
   params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
 end

 def find_user
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
 end

 def find_review
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
 end

end
```

_form which then gets rendered on show page:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
  <div id="rating-form">
    <label>Rating</label>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>

<script>
  $('#rating-form').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'review[rating]'
  });
</script>
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It seems like your `Rating` model has only one association to user (`belongs_to :user`). But you will need two: One to the user that is rated and one to the user that did the rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
end


#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :reviewed, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :reviewed_id
end

#app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @review = current_user.reviews.new
   end

   def create
      @review = current_user.reviews.new review_params
      @review.save
   end

   private

   def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment).merge(reviewed_id: params[:user_id])
   end
end

#app/views/reviews/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :rating %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This would mean you'll have to include a `reviewed_id` column in your `reviews` table.

You'll be able to access it using: `url.com/users/:user_id/reviews/new`

The application will automatically fill the `user_id` and `reviewed_id` fields, so the rest of your code should work with the upgrade.

The big problem you have is that you're basically recording the `user_id` (presumably of who *created* the review)... but have no way of stipulating who the review is *about*.

The above code fixes that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified my code with the code you provided and I have added the column, but I am still in a similar situation. I currently have a rating form on each user profile page, but now no matter on which user profile page I try and rate, the rating always affects the current_user.                        Also the form you posted gives me a "undefined method `reviews_path'" error, but "form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| " works.

Comment: I think I may have fixed it using "@user.reviews.new review_params" instead of "current_user.reviews.new" under reviews_controller.rb -> def new. I will check back soon after some testing and accept the answer.

Comment: Ok it doesn't seem to be fixed yet. The user_id and the reviewed_id are the same, and both set to the user id of the 'rated' user. (Not the rater).

Comment: Temporarily putting     @review.reviewed_id = current_user.id
in 'def create' in the reviews_controller fixes my problem. Everything is working as it should. A rater can rate another user, which then shows on the rated users profile.

Comment: Nice so did my code help, or did you stick to your original implementation?

Comment: I used your code, but edited a couple of things as there were conflicts with my original implementation. You helped me a lot, thank you. I have only been using rails for a few days so there are a couple of things I didn't understand though.